# Number of non-logical symbols and variables on first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

In a first order logic like https://haslab.github.io/MFES/2122/FOL-handout.pdf

Is there any requirement on the cardinality of the non-logical symbols? Can be uncountable in principle?
The same for the variables, can we define a language assuming we have an uncountable quantity of variables?

Comment: As far as I can see in the first-order languages which you reference the sets of variables, constants, functions, predicates are arbitrary disjoint sets. They can be as big or as small as you please.

Comment: In general there is no requirement on the cardianlity of non-logical symbols but some texts assume it to be countable because it makes certain theorem easier to prove(for instance one can prove the completness theorem for countable langauges without the use of infinitary non-constructive techniques(e.g $\mathsf{AC}$)), but most texts do not make this requirement. The number of variables on the other hand are taken to be countable.

Comment: See also [Infinitary Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/#1)

Comment: This kind of infinitary languages are required to construct models of ZFC? Like Von Neuman universe V, forcing extensions of V, etc?

Comment: I think I am still not ready to fully understand Von Neuman universe model or any forcing extension but I think if I rerread the basics with the perspective that in principle the non logical symbols could be as big as I wish it would be easier. I was mistaken somehow that this set must be enumerable, countable, computable, or with any similar constrain....

Comment: The completeness theorem (henkin construction) only requires a countable number of constants?